# Is there any way to get web page view source content?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I can't download the page content and save it as file name or to a string variable.
But i can watch in chrome the page source.

Is there anyway yo download or to get somehow the pageview source ?

For example this is a iew source of a site: view-source:http://www.one.co.il/
But it start with view-source

If i'm doing one of this im getting exception (403) Forbidden

```
using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                data = webClient.DownloadString("httP://www.one.co.il");
                //webClient.DownloadFile("http://www.one.co.il", @"c:\temp\tempppp.html");
            }
```

So i tried something like:

data = webClient.DownloadString("view-source:http://www.one.co.il");

But that give me exception i guess the view-source is not good as parameter.

Is there anyway to get the view source content each X minutes(like refresh and get it each X minutes) ?

Comment: You seem to have some significant misunderstandings in how browsers, HTTP and HTML work. The web request itself returns plain HTML. The browser interprets it and shows it as a graphical UI. The "view source" option only shows the original plain HTML again. When you do a simple request using e.g. `HttpWebRequest`, you'll get the same plain HTML. `view-source:XXX` is a feature of the browser, not of HTTP or URI (in fact, it's obviously invalid URI). Of course, the browser might be doing a lot more than you see - authentication, for example :)

Comment: It maybe the case that the target website refuses connections unless particular headers are set to "allowable" (by them) values. For example, *some* websites require a user agent to be set. Use a tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddlerool.com) to compare a request from your local friendly web browser, and your application, and try to better represent the behaviour of a web-browser...

Comment: It might also be you are behind a proxy blocking this request. Your code runs fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible it is called browser automation.

There are several very good ways to do this. I personally prefer Selenium.

```
var defaultamount = 10;
var url = "http://www.one.co.il";
string Result;
using (var driver = new FirefoxDriver())
{
    driver.Manage().Timeouts().ImplicitlyWait(defaultamount);
    _wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, defaultamount);
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    Result = driver.PageSource;
}
```

This means you will load the content, but wait at most 10 s. Alternatively you can wait for Javascript DOM to be loaded or what ever you basically want. Because of ajax enabled web content it is not easy to decide if content  you want is loaded.

Note this will open up web browser visually also if you do not want that you can turn it off.

Comment: One other way you might be interested is webbrowser control that you can host in your form (note it is based on Internet Explorer).

Comment: Why ever use such complicated way to get the page source? What was wrong with the actual code in the question from OP?

Comment: @PatrickHofman It is just **driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url); Result = driver.PageSource;** other code is just syntactical sugar. Just showed how to instantiate a wait driver, because question was about that.

Comment: But there is no need for extra libraries. The call in the question is just fine.